# MediaWiki docker image - how to set up properly

Tags: docker, mediawiki

I'm trying to setup my own Wiki very quickly.

I found this [MediaWiki docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki) that I can use.

I'm using Docker Compose, and I have the following `stack.yml` file (based on that of the link above).

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: mediawiki
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/images
      # After initial setup, download LocalSettings.php to the same directory as
      # this yaml and uncomment the following line and use compose to restart
      # the mediawiki service
      # - ./LocalSettings.php:/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php
  database:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_wiki
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: foo
```

There's a couple of problems and questions

1. Why do I need the `/var/www/html/images` volume? What is stored here that needs to persist? Is all persistent data not part of the database?
2. Apparently I must manually download `LocalSettings.php` and uncomment the `LocalSettings.php` volume after initial setup. There must be a better way to do this that is automatic?
3. How do I configure the database client in the Wiki and tell it what IP, user and password to use? I couldn't find any documentation on this. I'm guessing this must be done in `LocalSettings.php`? Also is there a way I can configure this inside my `stack.yml` so it doesn't have to be maintained separately and can be controlled with environment variables (although this isn't the most important thing right now)?

Comment: Re #3: I believe that's what the environment variables are for under the database section. I've never used that particular container though, so I can't really answer the rest. You might be better off asking those questions directly on their own support pages.

Comment: You might also find other containers easier/preferable, like this one for example: https://hub.docker.com/r/ubcctlt/mediawiki

Comment: @J.ScottElblein If I understand correctly, those environment variables configure the database, but are not given to the wiki to use to connect to the database. I'll take a look at that other image soon thanks

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Interesting, the docs for `ubcctlt/mediawiki` says that the default value of `MEDIAWIKI_DB_PASSWORD` is the password of the linked container. I didn't know this was possible, but apparently linking the containers allows it to detect and use the same password for connecting. So I'll try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do I need the /var/www/html/images volume? What is stored here that needs to persist? Is all persistent data not part of the database?

Nope. Uploaded files (img, and more depending your local settings) go there.
Be sure to backup them at same time than the db.

2. Apparently I must manually download LocalSettings.php and uncomment the LocalSettings.php volume after initial setup. There must be a better way to do this that is automatic?

My way of doing it, is to backup the DB of a brand new setup wiki, and then use it as a master for the new DB when starting a new wiki. Just be sure you are using always use same options (database type, etc).

3. How do I configure the database client in the Wiki and tell it what IP, user and password to use? I couldn't find any documentation on this. I'm guessing this must be done in LocalSettings.php? Also is there a way I can configure this inside my stack.yml so it doesn't have to be maintained separately and can be controlled with environment variables (although this isn't the most important thing right now)?

See answer in point 2. If you setup your DB by yourself, it is much more easier to automate the LocalSettings.php by yourself instead of using the wizard.

Enjoy